# In rtl, avoid rendering multiple components within a single test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

In rtl, avoid rendering multiple components within a single test?

For example, suppose that the sidebar folds when a button in the header is pressed.

To test this, I rendered the header and sidebar in one test like below.

```js
it("Fold/Unfold sidebar when click toggle button", async () => {
    // Given
    render(<Header />);
    render(<Sidebar />);

    const button = await screen.findByTestId("fold-sidebar-icon");
    const sidebar = await screen.findByTestId("sidebar");

    expect(sidebar).toHaveStyle({ width: styles.layout.sidebar.unfold });

    // When: click fold button
    fireEvent.click(button);
    // Then: fold sidebar
    expect(sidebar).toHaveStyle({ width: styles.layout.sidebar.fold });

    // When: click unfold button
    fireEvent.click(button);
    // Then: unfold sidebar
    expect(sidebar).toHaveStyle({ width: styles.layout.sidebar.unfold });
  });
```

Is this an action that should be avoided in the usual use of react testing libraries? If so, what is the appropriate test structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a clean solution. An easy clean solution would be to wrap your components into one. E.g.

```
const TestApp = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Sidebar />
  </div>
);
```

This way, you have both of your components displayed and rendered only once:

```
render(<TestApp />);
```

Otherwise, the test looks ok.